# Term for making a text more meaningful, intelligible, understandable and useful

Tags: synonyms

By annotating, rewording and/or other modifications such as:

- expanding first uses of acronyms
- title casing names, book/article titles
- adding footnotes with references for published mentions

Example of original text:

> A DJP as described in air matters travels at 80km/h.

Modified text:

> A Dynamic Jet Projectile (DJP) as described in [Air Matters](http://www.example.com) travels as fast as an inner city train (or 80km/h).

Comment: Perhaps 'Making the text more (or readily) accessible'?

Comment: Making the text clear and easy to read. Or clear, and a pleasure to read.

Comment: prettify. just joking

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as if you're looking for the name of the process. Saying an author 'revises' or makes revisions to a their own draft may suit your need.
You could say others help with revisions, but if they are improving a document up to its final version you would say they 'edit' it.

Comment: ["Editing is the process of selecting and preparing written, visual, audible, and film media used to convey information. The editing process can involve correction, condensation, organization, and many other modifications performed with an intention of producing a correct, consistent, accurate and complete work.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editing)

Answer (score 1):

**Demystifying.** As well as providing an accessible and comprehensible quantified  comparison.

An obscure [TLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym)  would indeed be mystifying to most general readers.  Hence the second draft is an improvement, targeted at that audience.

Answer (score 0):

You might call this converting (or translating) the text into "plain language."
https://www.plainlanguage.gov/about/definitions/

> The Plain Writing Act of 2010 defines plain language as:
>
> Writing that is clear, concise, well-organized, and follows other best practices appropriate to the subject or field and intended audience.